# My HTML content disappear after registration

Tags: php, html, mysql, templates, registration

I am working to my very first php web page. I downloaded a template. I did a registration form and integrated within the HTML content. When I press the register button, my php class register the user in the database and then the website loads the header and the footer but not the content of the page.

```
<?php

    require_once ('Connection\connection.php');

    class TRegistration
    {
        public function TRegistration()
        {
            global $g_sContent;
            $g_sContent = '';
        }

        public function ShowRegisterForm()
        {
            global $g_sContent;
            $g_sContent .= '
                <p>
        <!--        <table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="20">     -->

                    <form id="register" action="register.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">         
                    <fieldset >
                        <td>First Name</td><td> <input type="text" name="firstname"> </td> </tr><br></br>
                        <td>Last Name</td><td> <input type="text" name="lastname"> </td> </tr><br></br>
                        <tr> <td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" name="email"></td> </tr> <br></br>                       
                        <tr> <td>Password</td><td> <input type="password" name="pass"></td> </tr>  <br></br>
                        <tr> <td>Confirm Password </td><td><input type="password" name="cpass"></td> </tr>  <br></br>
                        <tr> <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up"></td> </tr>  </p>
                    </fieldset >
                </form>

        <!--        </table> -->        
                            ';  
        }       

        public function IsFormSent()
        {
            global $g_sContent;
            if(isset($_POST["firstname"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["pass"]) && isset($_POST["cpass"] ))
            {
                if($_POST["pass"]==$_POST["cpass"])
                {
                    return true;
                } else
                {
                    $g_sContent = "<text-red><p>The password doesn't match. Try again<br></br></p></text-red>";
                }
            }
            return false;
        }       

        public function RegisterUser()
        {
            global $g_sContent;

            $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
            $email = $_POST['email']; 
            $password = $_POST['pass']; 
            $cpassword = $_POST['cpass'];           

            global $g_conn;

            $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`,`First Name`,`Last Name`,`Nickname`,`Password`,`Email Address`) VALUES (0,'$firstname','$lastname','','$password','$email')";       
            $data = $g_conn->query($query); 

            if($data) 
            { 
                $g_sContent .= "<p>Your registration to the HUB it's complete...</p>"; 
            } else
            {
                $g_sContent .= "<p>Error registering to the HUB... </p>";   
            }       
        }
    }

    $g_sTitle = "Register";
    require_once ('Template\header.php');

    $g_sContentTitle = '<b>Register</b> to the HUB</b>';
    global $g_sContent;

    $Register = new TRegistration();
        if ($Register->IsFormSent() == false)
            $Register->ShowRegisterForm();
        else
        {
            $Register->RegisterUser();
            $g_sContent .= "<p>Error registering to the HUB... </p>";   
        }

    require_once ('Template\content.php');

    //include 'Template\footer.php';
?>
```

The template is using `js/waypoints.min.js` for animating content.

`Content.php` can be accessed here: http://pastebin.com/2yqu3eVL

Comment: What is in `Template\content.php`? Trying an `echo "content page";` in the `content.php` file should echo just fine.

Comment: The content.php is the template itself. I tried many times but the content is loaded dynamically using animations.

Comment: You can access the content.php from here http://pastebin.com/2yqu3eVL

Comment: Considering you have this: `require_once ('Template\content.php');include 'Template\footer.php';` one after the other, outside of any conditional statements there's no reason it shouldn't show them unless it is not finding `content.php`.

Comment: If you change those two lines as `require_once ('Template\footer.php');include 'Template\footer.php'` do you see the footer twice? Your php code is fine, either your styles are making the content page "disappear" from what you see, or the `content.php` is not accessible

Comment: You can access the content.php from here http://pastebin.com/2yqu3eVL . The code is using a dynamic animation to show the content.